# PHP/ORACLE oci_bind_by_name and RETURNING INTO to get PK

Tags: php, oracle, sql-returning

I'm doing a very basic insert into an Oracle DB, with a RETURNING INTO clause to get the primary key. I'm constantly getting a null return though, and I can't figure out for the life of me what the problem might be. Other than this problem, the row inserts perfectly fine. Code below:

```
$requestParentSQL = "INSERT INTO 
            KRANE_REQUEST (
                DATE_REQUESTED, 
                DATE_EMAILED, 
                PERSON_ID, 
                AUTHORISER_ID
                ) 
            VALUES (
                SYSDATE, 
                SYSDATE, 
                '$theUser', 
                '$theAuthoriser'
                )
            RETURNING 
                KRANE_REQUEST_ID 
            INTO 
                :NEW_KRID";

$oracleConnection = oci_connect(_DATABASEUSERNAME, _DATABASEPASSWORD, _DATABASE);
$oracleStatement = oci_parse($oracleConnection, $requestParentSQL);
oci_bind_by_name($oracleStatement, ':NEW_KRID', $theNewKRID, 8);
oci_execute($oracleStatement, OCI_DEFAULT);
oci_commit($oracleConnection);
oci_free_statement($oracleStatement);
oci_close($oracleConnection);
```

Comment: Is `NEW_KRID` an int or char? By default it will bind `SQLT_CHAR` since you have omitted the 5th parameter.

Comment: the Datatype is Number(12), I've tried defining SQLT_CHR and SQLT_INT, along with some of the other options just to see what would happen. But none of them returned a value.

Comment: FYI I tried using oci_bind_by_name for inserting  a date variable into the table, that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found. I was calling $theNEWKRID instead of $theNewKRID. My Bad.